# Validating US phone number in WTForms

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I'm working with a flask app and am using wtforms:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    phone = StringField('Phone', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(10)])
```

I've just added phone and am looking for a way to validate a US number. I came across http://wtforms-components.readthedocs.org/en/stable/#phonenumberfield but this does not appear to have phonenumberfield any longer. Whats the best way to handle this with wtfforms?

edited class:

```
class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    phone = StringField('Phone', validators=[DataRequired(),validate_phone('RegisterForm','phone'), Length(min=6, max=40)])

    def validate_phone(form, field):
        if len(field.data) > 16:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')
        try:
            input_number = phonenumbers.parse(field.data)
            if not (phonenumbers.is_valid_number(input_number)):
                raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')
        except:
            input_number = phonenumbers.parse("+1"+field.data)
            if not (phonenumbers.is_valid_number(input_number)):
                raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')
```

Comment: You could use a regex validator as an additional argument in your validators. Its long time ago since I used it, just try it. Hope it helps. Regexp(''^\w+$'', message="Enter a valid US Phone number"),

Comment: [According to the changelog](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-components/blob/35bdf49681eec08c1d4462954133bb45cb9644de/CHANGES.rst#0100-2016-01-28), `PhoneNumber` was [moved to WTForms-Alchemy](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-components/blob/35bdf49681eec08c1d4462954133bb45cb9644de/CHANGES.rst#0100-2016-01-28).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I made use of [python-phonenumbers](https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers) in a recent application. It uses google phone number parsing stuff. Here's how I used it:

```
from wtforms import ValidationError
import phonenumbers

class RegisterForm(Form):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=25)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email(), Length(min=6, max=40)])
    phone = StringField('Phone', validators=[DataRequired()])

    def validate_phone(form, field):
        if len(field.data) > 16:
            raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')
        try:
            input_number = phonenumbers.parse(field.data)
            if not (phonenumbers.is_valid_number(input_number)):
                raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')
        except:
            input_number = phonenumbers.parse("+1"+field.data)
            if not (phonenumbers.is_valid_number(input_number)):
                raise ValidationError('Invalid phone number.')
```

Comment: I left the phone input as a `StringField` as well

Comment: Thanks, How do you attach the validate_phone to the phone field? I tried:    phone = StringField('Phone', validators=[DataRequired(),validate_phone(RegisterForm,phone), Length(min=6, max=40)]) bit am getting unresolved function errors

Comment: You just need to add the validate_fieldname method to your class. See: http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/validators.html#custom-validators

Comment: If I understand correctly, I have , please see a simplified version of class in edit above. I must not be understanding correctly.

Comment: Use my class exactly as is. You do not need this: `validate_phone('RegisterForm','phone')`. The `validate_fieldname` method is special to a form inheriting a wtform object (a flask-wtform object in this case `Form`). `validate_fieldname`'s arguments are also special `form` and `field`. But don't take my word for it, give it a try. Of course for this to work, you need to call a validate method on the form `.validate` or with flask-wtf `.validate_on_submit`.

Comment: Thanks it does work. I did not realize that. I'll have to read further on this.

Answer (score 1):

I made use of the built-in `PhoneNumberField` in `wtforms` components. Here's how I used it.

```
from wtforms_components import PhoneNumberField

class UserForm(Form):
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(
        country_code='US'
        display_format='national'
    )
```

Comment: As of `0.10.0` version of `wtforms_components` the `PhoneNumberField` has been moved to [WTForms-Alchemy](https://github.com/kvesteri/wtforms-alchemy)